# Why is there a difference in this Base64 conversion?

Tags: powershell, base64

Using the following function I get two different results from converting the contents of a file to Base64 and I have no idea why.

```
function p-b64 {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="File")]
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="File")]
    [string]
    $File,

    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="String")]
    [string]
    $String
)

if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "File") {
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $File -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
        return $encoded
}
elseif ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "String") {
        $File = "$env:TEMP\foob64.txt"
        echo $String > $File    
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $File -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
        return $encoded
}

}
```

On one hand I directly convert a file from my desktop and these are the results:

```
$File = "C:\Users\micha\Desktop\foob64.txt"
$encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $File -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
$encoded

Results = cwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAbgBvAHQAZQBwAGEAZAA=
```

But when I echo a string to a file and use the same code to convert it I get different results. why?

```
$File = "$env:TEMP\foob64.txt"
echo $String > $File
$encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $File -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
$encoded

Results = cwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAbgBvAHQAZQBwAGEAZAANAAoA
```

Why are they different?
I'm trying to write a function that will accept a file path or a string and convert it to Base64. I just do not understand why the results are diffferent.

Comment: Can you add the result of `Format-Hex -Path ...foob64.txt` (for both files) ?

Comment: Why do you write the string to a temp file in the first place? Instead, convert it directly to B64: `$encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($String))`

Comment: Because when I use what you've provided to try and convert powershell scripts with quotes and semi colons it errors out

Comment: You would need to share an example of how it fails doing what zett42 mentioned above (A minimal reproducible example). This also applies if you want an answer to your initial question, without looking at the files `Format-Hex` is not possible to answer. We would be assuming things...

Comment: Then the error must be somewhere else, because my suggestion doesn't modify the string data in any way (besides the encoding, which round-trips perfectly). When you write `$String > $File` PowerShell appends a newline, so that might be the problem with your attempted solution.

Comment: When I get home from work I will include the error out message.

Comment: `[convert]::FromBase64String('cwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAbgBvAHQAZQBwAGEAZAANAAoA')` is `<CR><LF>`  tailed…

Comment: Is there a way I can write to the temp file and remove that newline?

Comment: Instead of reading the file as a string (and then converting that string back to bytes to encode them) I'd suggest to read the file as a bye array and convert those bytes directly to base64

Comment: "*Is there a way I can write to the temp file and remove that newline?*" ➔ [Set-Content -NoNewline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)